# how to run python file in different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several python files, and I want to run in a different directory where it will search for a particular pattern from 100s of files. Let's say I have the python file in `/home/jay` directory, and I have 100s of files in `/home/jay/data` directory.

What can I do to achieve this?

**My python code is :**

```
import re
import os

os.chdir(r'/home/jay/data/')
files = open('*')
for line in files :
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('Model' , line):
        print(line)
```

**I'm getting following error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jay/test.py", line 4, in ?
    files = open('*')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '*'
```

Comment: Go into your Python site-packages folder and open up a setup.py from NumPy or other to see how they are getting all the file names good luck

Comment: don't see setup.py file in site-packages. not sure which files i should look for. there other module imported such as BeautifulSoup, requests etc.. beginner in python, so pardon if this is silly question.

Comment: If you really wrote `files = open(*)` you wouldn't be getting an `IOError` but rather a `SyntaxError`. Please post your actual code.

Comment: `print(line)\`` is also  syntax error.

Comment: Also, you can't get an error saying `No such file or directory: '/home/jay/Data/*'` if your line really reads `os.chdir(r'/home/jay/data/')`. Please fix your code!

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Close vote retracted. Don't forget the stray backtick at the end.

Comment: @Mad Physicst : Sorry. i was changing the path to '*' and actual path and i messed up while putting actual code and error combination. post is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir). It will give you a list of all the file names in the specified directory, which defaults to the current directory. The reason that `'*'` does not work is that it is a command-line construct that is expanded by your shell. You can only really use it in a shell or script that supports that sort of expansion. Since `open` does not go through the shell, it tries to find a file actually named `*`. Also, `open` can only deal with one file at a time.

```
import os, os.path, re

os.chdir(r'/home/jay/data/')
files = os.listdir()
for name in files:
    # Skip directories
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        continue
    with open(name) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if re.search('Model' , line):
                print(line)
```

That being said, as a matter of personal preference, I generally avoid using `os.chdir`. Instead, I prefer specifying full paths using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). Here is your example rewritten to do that:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isdir

folder = '/home/jay/data'
files = listdir(folder)
for name in files:
    name = join(folder, name)
    # Skip directories
    if isdir(name):
        continue
    with open(name) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if 'Model' in line:
                print(line)
```

I took the liberty of removing the regex completely since it only serves to slow things down in you have many files. If you do use a regex for some more complicated scenario, compile if before you use it using [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).

Furthermore, you are free to use relative paths here if you want. For example, if you are always running from `/home/jay`, you can set `folder = 'data'` instead of `folder = '/home/jay/data'` in the second example.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko. Thanks for that.

Comment: Try that code. gave me syntax error: File "test.py", line 6
    with open(name) as file:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Tired your 2nd exapmple without regex :

File "test.py", line 7
    with open(join(folder, name)) as file:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Jay. It looks like you are having issues with `with`. I have no problem running this code. How are you running your script exactly?

Comment: I'm running code normal like. " python test.py " from my company unix server.

Comment: @Jay. And what is the output of `python --version`?

Comment: @ Mad Physicist : `$ python -V
 Python 2.4.3`

Comment: @Jay. Your question specified `python 3.x` in the tags. `with` was introduced in python 2.5. I am amazed that you have such an old interpreter.

Comment: @Jay, You should either find a Python 3 interpreter (perhaps install anaconda on your server), or update your question with the correct python version. For older versions of Python that don't have any of the more "modern" constructs, this is especially important.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist, Sorry, i just started learning and getting hands on python. So i never new that with introduced in 2.5. I didn't find any tags for 2.4.3, so i tagged 'python3'. I think i would update the python version and will try the same script. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenk : Thanks for your help !!

Comment: @ Mad Physicist Wait a second.  i just found out that there has python 3.3.2 install as well. I just need to run using 'python3.3 test.py' . I ran it and i got output with some error at the end. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(join(folder, name)) as file:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'Data/.svn'

Comment: @Jay. You should really look at [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/anaconda-overview) for this sort of thing. It lets you install different Python environments for the local user. Also, the correct tag is python 2.x if you are using version 2.something. Now it doesn't matter though.

Comment: Seriously though, I'm amazed that you have those interpreters. I am not sure if either version is even officially supported any more. Use 2.7 for Py2 and 3.6+ for Py3 if you can manage it.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist, Thank You Sir. Not sure what anaconda is, but i would really look into that.

Comment: @Jay. It's a very popular system for managing Python environments. If this answer did it for you , you should select it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist , Thanks!! . I did click on check mark.